# Storing Dates in MySQL through Codeigniter. Date stored as 0000:00:00

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have large form with 30+ user inputs including two date fields as contract start date and contract end date. I am using Jquery UI to capture the date on frontend.

Controller:

```
$data = $this->input->post(); // returns all POST items without XSS filter
            $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-info"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">close</button>', '</div>');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('nameMusicCompany', 'Music Company Name', 'required');

            if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
            {
                $this->load->view('pages/clientview/client_page');
                $this->load->view('templates/footer');
            }
            else 
            {

                $result = $this->client_model->create_new_client($data);
                if($result !== false)
                {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('client_insert_message', '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible text-center" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>New Client Created Successfully!</div>');
                    redirect('Client');
                }
            }
```

I have used `$this->input->post()`to get the value of all 30 fields in a array and assigned it to $data.

Model to insert data in MySQL table:

```
public function create_new_client($data)
        {
                $this->db->insert('client_data', $data);

                if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0)
                {
                        return true;
                }
                else 
                {
                        return false;
                }
        }
```

It's working fine except that the dates are stored as 0000:00:00 in table. Both the columns have data type as TIMESTAMP in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

mysql timestamp field accept `yyyy-mm-dd H:i:s` format of date so you have to pass date into this format not the UNIX timestamp.

Convert the dates like this:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $your_date);
```